# CNN result replication on tensorflow

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am trying to replicate the first Sequential example in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAciKiDP2bo

using the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')/255
y_train = y_train.astype('float32')/255

# Sequential model
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu'), # 'same'
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(10),
    ]
)
model.summary()

model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=3e-4),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10, verbose=2)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
```

The accuracy I get is 0.1 vs 0.7 which the author shows in the video. Could somebody point me to the issue with the code, my computer config etc?

Answer (score 3):

It's cause your line "y_train = y_train/255" should be "x_test = x_test / 255". It doesn't make sense to scale the y labels; what the division by 255 accomplishes is scaling the RGB values of our input images (in x_train/x_test) from between 0-255 to between 0-1, which is more in line with what neural net initializations expect.

Check timestamp 3:36 of the video for confirmation.

Comment: really appreciate this. I could not see that! thanks.